# Networking wiring 1000 MB switch with 100 MB router with DHCP

Tags: networking, dhcp, wiring

I would like to buy a 1000 Mb network switch and connect it with 100 Mb router which have DHCP server.

So I would like to know it computers connected on the 1Gb switch would be able to connect @ 1Gb network speed? I an not sure since DHCP server is 100 Mb, and it initialize the connection ... Would help if I would set manually IPs or this makes no difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

DHCP doesn't determine the speed of the connection, it simply assigns an IP address and a few other configuration details, such as router, DNS servers etc.

The network speed is negotiated between the NIC and the switch independantly of DHCP.

Comment: So computers connected on the switch would be able to connect @1Gb speed (if they have 1Gb NIC of course), right? I would like really be sure, because I an going to buy this stuff.

Comment: Yes - they will be able to talk at gigabit to other machines connected to the switch with gigabit NICs.